# PowerBI Report Builder charts cropped

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am currently using the Power BI Report Builder for a paginated report which seems to be a light version of the SSRS.
Anyways, looks like my Charts are cropped for whatever reason. Is this known or somehow a bug/limitation to my installation?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling the application did the trick...